# Wrong location of components in xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm started making android app in xamarin using c# and I want support with adding controls from toolbox onto design surface.

Problem - when I drag the any of controls and place it onto design surface, it automaticaly set its location to the top-left corner, but I need to set other location - how to do?

I expect, that controls will sort themself under each of them - but now all of controls are situated in the top-left corner. Thanks for any advice!!

Comment: I don't know the newest IDE version, but this behavior looks like a layout view container... Probably AbsoluteLayout ou RelativeLayout. Can you switch to source code view? Is there a XAML editor option?

Comment: Do you have a `<Grid />` in the XAML? That's typically the reason it does that.

Comment: Perhaps you would do well to read the documentation in the UI designer for Xamarin.Android: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/android-designer/

Answer (score 0):

You would need a container like `FrameLayout` first. Then you can add multiple items inside and drag them around within it's dimensions.